# How to write unittest for a module which is only supported in Python >(3,0) while the rest are supported across all the version?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to exclude certain unit tests from running if the test are running in `python < (3,0)`. I tried using `@unittest.skipIf` to skip the class of tests. Tests are excluded but the import statements are still executed which results into import errors as certain libraries used for the module is not installed if `python < (3,0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    # unitests
```

This will check the python version, and only when that python version is what you want it will run.